# Optimizing code to generate static

Tags: optimization, processing, p5.js

I am learning p5.js and wanted to generate a "static/noise texture" like so:

[image]

This is the code:

```js
for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
  for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    noiseVal = random(0,1);
    stroke(255, noiseVal*255);
    point(x,y);
  }
}
```

This produces the desired outcome but it's obviously pretty slow since it has to iterate over every single pixel. What would be a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is really not the best way to do with p5.js.

[Take a look to the p5's pixels array.](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pixels)

When I run the following code, the function that use the pixels array run 100 times faster.

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(50, 50);
    background(255);

    let start, time;

    start = performance.now();
    noise_1();
    time = performance.now() - start;
    print("noise_1 : " + time);

    start = performance.now();
    noise_2();
    time = performance.now() -start;
    print("noise_2 : " + time);

}

// Your code
function noise_1() {
    for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            noiseVal = random(0,1);
            stroke(noiseVal*255);
            point(x,y);
        }
    }
}

// same with pixels array
function noise_2() {
    loadPixels();
    for (let i=0; i < pixels.length; i+=4){
        noiseVal = random(0,    255);
        pixels[i] = pixels[i+1] = pixels[i+2] = noiseVal;
    }
    updatePixels();
}
```

output :

```
noise_1 : 495.1
noise_2 : 5.92
```

Comment: Nice, I hadn't heard of that! I'll look into it. Just as an aside, when I run the pixels array function of your code, nothing gets rendered on the screen. Is there something else I have to do?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  The pixels array is empty if nothing have been drawn on the canvas. So just add a `background()` . (I've edited the post.)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To generate a single frame of static, you're going to have to iterate over each pixel. You could make your blocks larger than a single pixel, but that will only reduce the problem, not get rid of it completely.

Instead, you can probably get away with pre-computing a few images of static (let's say 10 or so). Save these as a file or to an off-screen buffer (the `createGraphics()` function is your friend), and then draw those images instead of drawing each pixel every frame.

Comment: That makes sense. I would have liked to generate a completely random image each time, but this is a good compromise. Thanks!

Comment: @Manu You could generate an entire directory of images. Or you could generate something like 100 smaller blocks of static that you put together (randomly) to form a larger image every time.